# how to specify gcc options while building ROS programs

Tags: ros, gcc, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
When I compile my (non-ROS) programs with the third party libraries, I need to provide gcc with some options as well as paths to include head files and libraries. Usually this is how the gcc command looks like:

*gcc -I**my_include_files_path**   -**SOME_OPTIONS**   -L**my_library_files_path**  source.c*

Now I want to use these third party libraries with ROS, how can I specify those options in ROS?

With Many Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10554/how-to-specify-gcc-options-while-building-ros-programs/) by [HZhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/814/hzhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-10

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this has been answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/1509/how-to-build-ros-nodes-with-other-libraries) already.

The ROS build is based on CMake. You can find a basic tutorial on CMake [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3